# How can I disable PHPStorm from saving to buffer?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm not sure exactly what's happening or if it's a default setting, but PHPStorm seems to be auto-saving files to some sort of buffer if I have not actually saved the file yet. I can close the editor and open it back up to still see unsaved changes, or perhaps it actually saves the changes on exit, I'm not sure which.

I often close the editor and re-load a file when I'm not sure what changes may have transpired since I last opened the file to make sure I don't save unintentional changes, but I can't do that with PHPStorm autosaving or whatever it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable such behaviour -- auto save is one of the core functionalities that this IDE relies on and can be triggered at any moment in time.

You can use **[Local History](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Local+History+in+PhpStorm)** to restore file to a previously saved state.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6460

**P.S.**
If you will give it a bit of time (few weeks, month -- depends on person and habits), you will get used to it just like many other people who using this IDE.

---

From [this particular comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6460#comment=27-366729):

> Auto-saving is built in very deeply and many IDE features just won't work without it (e.g. compilation, running, etc). For reverting unwanted changes there's VCS, Local History and Undo.
>
> Currently we don't plan to add a possibility to disable auto-save.

Comment: This is so sad, it would be an awesome IDE.

Comment: @nbrogi It is already. It's just a matter of getting used to this. Yes, this means possible change in your habits/workflow (e.g paying attention where you type; copy file first and then make changes instead of type first  and then save as etc). Many people did it already. It was very unusual to start working with such feature in first week. But after 2 months it became "how did I live without it before".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

**To enable preserving temporary files while saving changes**

1. In the IDE Settings section of the Settings dialog box, click General.
   Select the Use "safe write" check box.
2. Note that if this check box is selected, modified file will be first saved as a temporary file. If the save operation is completed successfully, the temporary file will renamed, and the original file will be deleted.